# Dying in Dead Island

Tags: dead-island

If you die in Dead Island is there a way for you to get out of the mission you are playing and return to free play without having to quit to the main menu?

Comment: I might be able to answer better if it's a particular mission that you're stuck on that you can tell me so I can tell you if it's possible.

Comment: For the record, this user hasn't visited since ten days after they posted this question, so there is little likelihood that they will accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Or join someone's game and your save will become that one.

Answer (score 0):

I know in the successor, Dead Island: Riptide you could quit a mission and return to free play without dying, and I would imagine the case in the original is the same, as they're very similar

Answer (score 0):

Most missions, you can complete at your own pace. Few missions, and I believe those are escort missions, have a fail condition that resets you back to its location if you try to "return to free play". If you've already begun an escort mission, I think that you may be stuck in it until you complete it. You could try selecting a different mission in your mission log, but I don't think it'll help.

I don't think that quitting to the main menu allows you to "return to free play" either. That option is more of a "take a break from or never play this game again" option.